# what is the purpose of two config files for Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2

This is my current project structure:

```
pom.xml
/src
  /main
    /resources
      hibernate.cfg.xml
      /META-INF
        persistence.xml
```

I have very similar configuration params in both files (`hibernate.cfg.xml` and `persistence.xml`), which looks strange, but this is what I saw in many online examples and tutorials. I can't understand why do I need to have two files. Is it possible to work just with one? Please explain.

ps. For example, should I declare `hibernate.dialect` in both files, or just one will be enough? If so, which one to use?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you are using Hibernate's proprietary API, you'll need the `hibernate.cfg.xml`. If you are using JPA i.e. Hibernate EntityManager, you'll need the `persistence.xml`.

So you generally don't need both as you use **either** Hibernate proprietary API or JPA.

However, if you **were using** Hibernate Proprietary API and already have a `hibernate.cfg.xml` (and `hbm.xml` XML mapping files) but want to start using JPA,  you can reuse the existing configuration files by referencing the `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the `persistence.xml` in the `hibernate.ejb.cfgfile` property - and thus have both files. Reusing existing `hbm.xml` files is IMO a realistic scenario that could justify keeping both (even if I'd probably migrate to JPA annotations on the long run).

#### References

- Hibernate EntityManager

  - [2.2.2. Bootstrapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html_single/#setup-configuration-bootstrapping)

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I'm also using `hibernate3:hbm2ddl` and I think that it needs `hibernate.cfg.xml`, right? And I feel that it doesn't know how to work with `persistence.xml`. Am I right? I need two files in this case? (I'm working ONLY with JPA)

Comment: @Vincenzo According to [this article](http://users.mafr.de/~matthias/articles/generating-ddl-scripts.html), `hibernate3:hbm2ddl` can be used with a `jpaconfiguration` and a `persistence.xml`. So no, you don't need an `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Answer (score 20):

`hibernate.cfg.xml` is for Hibernate; `persistence.xml` is for JPA.

If you do Hibernate without JPA, you don't need the latter.

If you do JPA, you have to have a provider implementation, which means Hibernate, EclipseLink, etc.  (There may be other legit JPA implementations, but I don't have time to check right now.)

Comment: and I have to duplicate parameters in both files?