# JPA With Hibernate Error: [PersistenceUnit: JPA] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

I have a problem with Java Persistence API and Hibernate.
My situation of project is:

[image]

My persistence.xml file is:

```
<persistence 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="JPA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.david.Libro</class>
        <class>com.david.Categoria</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.transactionType" value="RESOURCE_LOCAL" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/arquitecturaJava" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And i create EntityManagerFactory in:

```
private static EntityManagerFactory buildEntityManagerFactory() 
    {
        try 
        {
            return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPA");
        } 
        catch (Throwable ex) 
        {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
            //throw new RuntimeException("Error al crear la factoria de JPA:->"+ ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My error is about create EntityManagerFactory:

```
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: JPA] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at com.david.JPAHelper.buildEntityManagerFactory(JPAHelper.java:14)
    at com.david.JPAHelper.<clinit>(JPAHelper.java:8)
    at com.david.Categoria.buscarTodos(Categoria.java:93)
    at com.david.FormularioInsertarLibroAccion.ejecutar(FormularioInsertarLibroAccion.java:25)
    at com.david.ControladorLibros.doGet(ControladorLibros.java:38)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping com.david.Libro
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.addClass(Configuration.java:2638)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3512)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3466)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1355)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1756)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    ... 27 more
```

Part of Libro and Categoria classes code is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Categorias")
public class Categoria implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoria") 
    private String id;
    private String descripcion;

....
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Libros")
public class Libro implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    private String isbn;
    private String titulo;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name="categoria")
    private Categoria categoria;

....
```

My file of Hibernate Configuration is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/arquitecturajava</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        
        <mapping class="com.david.Categoria"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.david.Libro"></mapping>
        
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Any ideas!!
Thank´s!!

Comment: When rethrowing an exception, it is more useful if you include the original exception as a nested exception, so the original stacktrace can be examined: `new RuntimeException("my message", ex)`

Comment: Before throwing a new RuntimeException, print the stacktrace with `ex.printStackTrace();`, or using the (better) strategy commented by @SJuan76.

Comment: You should not catch anything at all. If creation of the `EntityManagerFactory` fails, you cannot recover anyway.

Comment: I have modified, the show of error with PrintOfTrace. But is the same i don´t know how solve this error.

Comment: Your error is: `DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping com.david.Libro`, as shown by the line `Caused by` in your stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry for my cuestion, but where is the duplication?

Comment: Maybe `Libro` and `Categoria` maps to the same table? Show the classes please.

Comment: You have to post your `com.david.Libro` entity code so that we can examine the problem.

Comment: "Raised whenever a duplicate for a certain type occurs. Duplicate class, table, property name etc."

Comment: Classes Libro and Categoria are linked with Hibernate Annotations. The tables of my BD are Libros and Categorias.

Comment: Paste your `hibernate.cfg.xml` as well. I think you have mapped your classes both in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `persistence.xml`.

Comment: I have pasted my code of Hibernate Configuration.

Comment: Balázs Mária Németh, you´re right!!! I´ve deleted this lines in persistence.xml: <class>com.david.Libro</class>
   <class>com.david.Categoria</class>

Comment: OK, see my answer as well and accept if that was the solution please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need both `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `persistence.xml` in this case. Have you tried removing `hibernate.cfg.xml` and mapping everything in `persistence.xml` only?

But as the other answer also pointed out, this is not okay like this:

```
@Id
@JoinColumn(name = "categoria") 
private String id;
```

Didn't you want to use `@Column` instead?

Comment: If you dont add @Column, Hibernate catch all of yours properties as columns. If i delete hibernate.cfg.xml i cant access to my BD.        " /hibernate.cfg.xml not found"

Comment: For other hand if i dont delete hibernate.cfg.xml and comment classes links in persistence.xml the error is "Transaction not active"

Comment: Have a look at this post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807503/what-is-the-purpose-of-two-config-files-for-hibernate You don't need both. You should go with your persistence.xml. But maybe it's not correctly configured! But the issue was because of what I told you I guess :)

Comment: Ok, part of Hibernate is true. Its necesary delete hibernate.cfg.xml. But my error: " javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: JPA] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory" and "Duplicate class/entity mapping com.david.Libro" not solve...

Comment: Finally found!! Supress hibernate.cfg.xml and hbm files but not delete @JoinColumn annotations. Thank´s!!

Answer (score 1):

Suppress the `@JoinColumn(name="categoria")` on the ID field of the `Categoria` class and I think it will work.

Comment: Is the same, with o without this line in Categoria or Libro, the error is the same.

Comment: After delete hibernate.cfg.xml and delete @JoinColumn annotation od Categoria, the error is " org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping com.david.Libro"...i don´t know why..

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after adding the following dependency in pom,

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
 <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use above annotation if someone is facing :--org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider persistence provider when it attempted to create the container entity manager factory for the paymentenginePU persistence unit. The following error occurred: [PersistenceUnit: paymentenginePU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
** This is a solution if you are using Audit table.@Audit

Use:- @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED) on superclass.