# Do i have to put both persistence.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml ? it seems to have a conflict when I deploy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, configuration, persistence

I'm new in personal projects, and i have a confusion in start with JPA/Hibernate 2.1

Some tutorials say that you have to put persistence.xml in the /META-INF folder.
And some others say that you might have a hibernate.cfg.xml in the root folder.

What is the best practice ?

Is there one for local deployment and another for remote deployment ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the purpose of two config files for Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807503/what-is-the-purpose-of-two-config-files-for-hibernate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA is the Java Persistence API specification. It's just an API. Hibernate is a persistence framework that implements the JPA specification. There are others implementations of JPA like EclipseLink.

If you want to use the JPA API, with Hibernate as a persistence provider, you need to use `persitence.xml` file.

If you are not using the JPA, and just want to use the Hibernate api directly, you could use `hibernate.cfg.xml` or just an `hibernate.properties` file.